# $f(x)=\cos x - e^{-x}$. Find min/max and prove supremum.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

**Question**: Prove that $\sup f([0,\infty))=1$, for $f(x)=\cos x - e^{-x}$.

**My attempt**: I started by showing that $\forall x \in [0,\infty)$, $f(x) \le 1$ as follows:

$$f(x) = \cos x - e^{-x} = \cos x - \frac{1}{e^x} \le 1 - \frac{1}{e^x} \le 1.$$

Here I used the fact that $\cos x \le 1$ and $e^{x}$ is positive.

Now I want to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists x \in [0,\infty)$ s.t. $f(x) > 1 - \epsilon$.

But I don't know how to kick off the proof, I'd like for some hints that can direct me.

Comment: Hint: Find a sufficiently large $x$ where $\cos(x)=1$ and $e^{-x}<\epsilon$. (Remember that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}=0$)

Comment: If I choose $x=2\pi n$ s.t $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $cos(2\pi n)-\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}=1-\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}$. We want the following: $1-\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}>1-\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow -\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}>-\epsilon \Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}} <\epsilon$. Is that enough to complete the proof? or I have to point out something regarding $n$?.

Comment: Well, you need to choose $n$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}<\epsilon$ indeed holds. Since the sequence $\frac{1}{e^{2\pi n}}$ converges to $0$, such $n$ indeed exists.

Comment: Thank you! Now I get it.